# What is the min and max sizes of UDP & TCP header?

Tags: tcp, udp

What is the min and max sizes of UDP & TCP header?
I saw many saying about the normal sizes, hardly to find the min and max sizes

Answer (score 6):

Look at the header format for both protocols. Both their headers are defined sizes.

For UDP, the head itself is 8 bytes, 2 of which are allocated for the payload size (in bytes). Since there are 8 bits in a byte, that means the payload size can be a maximum of 2^16-1 bytes. The minimum size is just a header with no payload, and the maximum is the header size plus the maximum payload. Note that the header size is fixed.

For IPv4 TCP, it is slightly more complicated. The mandatory TCP header is 20 bytes (minimum size), with optional protocol options appended to the end of the header. The size of the header in 32 bit words is defined by `offset`, which has 4 bits allocated to it. Therefore offset can have a max value of 2^4-1, or 15. This means the maximum TCP header size is 60 bytes (15*4 bytes).

Edit: removed unnecessary points.

Comment: "The size of a TCP payload is defined by its sequence number" is very poorly worded. I would just delete everything from that sentence on: he didn't ask about it.

Comment: Realized mid way through editing I forgot they were only asking for header sizes.